# Adding an index to classicthesis

Tags: classicthesis, makeidx

I've been trying to add an index to my classicthesis document, in addition to a glossary (since [they're not the same thing](https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-glossary-and-vs-index/)). I've done the usual bits:

```
% in the preamble
\PassOptionsToPackage{listings,parts,%
  eulerchapternumbers=true,
  dottedtoc=false,
  tocaligned=false,
  pdfspacing=true,
  floatperchapter=false,
  linedheaders=false,
  subfig=true,
  eulermath=true,
  parts=true,
  drafting=true,
}{classicthesis}

..

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

...

% in the text
Some term\index{defined}.

%before the end:
\printindex
```

However, the compilation always stops with errors of this type:

```
[35] [36] [37] (./main-electronic.ind

! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.1 \begin{theindex}

? error: could not open document

H
You've lost some text.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
?

Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   {
l.5 \end{theindex}

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   }
l.5 \end{theindex}

?
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
                   }
l.5 \end{theindex}

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   {
l.5 \end{theindex}

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   }
l.5 \end{theindex}

?
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
                   }
l.5 \end{theindex}

?
! Infinite glue shrinkage found in a paragraph.
<inserted text> \par

l.5 \end{theindex}

?

Overfull \hbox (242.98398pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
[] []
```

The `ind` file seems fine:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item defined, \hyperpage{14}

\end{theindex}
```

and so does the idx file:

```
\indexentry{defined|hyperpage}{14}
```

I've not been able to find much information on using `makeidx` with `classicthesis` or anything that says that they should not be used together. A post or two said something about `classicthesis` redefining `\item`, but not much on how to work around it.

Would anyone have any hints on this? Either on how to get it to work, or if they don't work together, why not? Any additional info on making an index (with `glossaries` or another package) would alsy be appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: The current version of `classicthesis` is largely incompatible with `scrbook`, because it uses several packages that make it balk. Look at the log file and you'll find several warnings: one, in particular, is probably connected with the issue, as it is about `titlesec`. Use `imakeidx` instead of `makeidx`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to build, even if I haven't understood what caused the error in the first place.

I investigated a bit---read through the whole error and so on. It seemed to come down to the `\begin{theindex}` bit in the `ind` file. A simple test confirmed this. I simply replaced `\begin{theindex}` with `\begin{itemize}` (and the closing bit also), and the compilation went just fine.

So I went about looking at how I could replace `theindex` with something else. Using a style file for the index seemed to be the way. Something like this (taken from `man makeindex` and tweaked):

```
preamble
"\\begin{itemize}
{\\small\n"
postamble
"\n\n}
\\end{itemize}\n"
```

However, when I went to look at how to pass this to the `\makeindex` command, I learned that this cannot be done using the `makeidx` package.
A little more looking brought me to the `imakeidx` package that allows one to pass options to the command. The `\makeindex` command, becomes so: `\makeindex[options=-s simplesyle.ist]`.

This ran well, and the compilation worked.
Out of idle curiosity, I removed the options from `\makeindex`, and to my utter suprise, the compilation still worked---no need for a style file at all with `imakeidx`?!

So, the solution here is to use `imakeidx` instead of `makeidx`.
I don't yet know why this is the case, so if anyone can shed some light on the issue here, I'm sure we'd all be very grateful.

Comment: I found nothing about index in any shape other than to confirm your initial errors Glad you found an answer but may be worth raising as a question at https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/issues

Comment: Time to ask @egreg: What does imakeidx do differently from makeidx? Here's a MWE:
`\documentclass[footinclude,headinclude]{scrbook} 

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Test Chapter} \lipsum[1-3] Some term defined\index{define}.

    \section{A Section} \lipsum[2-8] Some term\index{term} defined.

    \printindex

\end{document}`

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Well, `imakeidx` redefines `theindex` in a way completely different than `scrbook`.